# What is the default hash code that Mathematica uses?

Tags: hash, wolfram-mathematica

The online documentation says

```
Hash[expr] 
  gives an integer hash code for the expression expr.
Hash[expr,"type"]
  gives an integer hash code of the specified type for expr.
```

It also gives "*possible* hash code types":

- "Adler32" Adler 32-bit cyclic redundancy check
- "CRC32"   32-bit cyclic redundancy check
- "MD2" 128-bit MD2 code
- "MD5" 128-bit MD5 code
- "SHA" 160-bit SHA-1 code
- "SHA256"  256-bit SHA code
- "SHA384"  384-bit SHA code
- "SHA512"  512-bit SHA code

Yet none of these correspond to the default returned by `Hash[expr]`.

So my questions are:

- What method does the default `Hash` use?
- Are there any other hash codes built in?

Comment: Related: "[Default behaviour of `Hash[expr]` and hashing in different versions of *Mathematica*](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68954/280)."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default hash algorithm is, more-or-less, a basic 32-bit hash function applied to the underlying expression representation, but the exact code is a proprietary component of the Mathematica kernel. It's subject to (and has) change between Mathematica versions, and lacks a number of desirable cryptographic properties, so I personally recommend you use MD5 or one of the SHA variants for any serious application where security matters. The built-in hash is intended for typical data structure use (e.g. in a hash table).

The named hash algorithms you list from the documentation are the only ones currently available. Are you looking for a different one in particular?

Comment: @Michael Do you know if there a way to "introspect" Mathematica to get this kind of info? And also: Why isn't the "type" param of the Hash function implemented as an "option" (->) ? Mmmm may be I should post a question ...

Comment: @Michael I'm actually using it to speed up a calculation. I have some very long expressions built out of `NonCommutativeMultiply` that I need to `Collect` the coefficients and solve for linear dependence. Hashing the `NonCommutativeMultiply`s speeds things up by about a factor of 2. So all I need is the uniqueness of the hash. The question was asked only out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm not sure why `Hash` uses a second argument and not options, nor is there any way to introspect out possible algorithms, although that's a great suggestion.

Comment: Also, @Simon, keep in mind most hash functions (including `Hash[]`, MD5 and SHA) aren't "perfect" (i.e., injective), and unfortunately, especially not `Hash`. Evaluate and consider this: `Length[DeleteDuplicates[Hash /@ Range[10^6]]]` =)

Comment: @Simon But `Length@DictionaryLookup[___] - Length@DeleteDuplicates@(Hash /@ DictionaryLookup[___]) == 1` :), so I think you should test the injective property for your app

Comment: @belisarius It is interesting that the only two words in default English Dictionary that hash the same are "Occidentals" and "umped"...

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. It's not being used in a critical part of my program and the final results will be tested without the hash - so I don't expect any problems.

Comment: @Simon So derive the algorithm by knowing that :D

Comment: In fairness, I wouldn't expect a function called 'Hash' to necessarily be cryptographically secure by default. There are loads of use cases for hashes that don't require those properties.

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing some reverse engeneering on 32 and 64 bit Windows version of Mathematica 10.4 and that's what I found:

### **32 BIT**

It uses a [Fowler–Noll–Vo hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#FNV-1_hash) (FNV-1, with multiplication before) with 16777619 as FNV prime and ‭84696351‬ as offset basis. This function is applied on [Murmur3-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) hashed value of the address of expression's data (MMA uses a pointer in order to keep one instance of each data). The address is eventually resolved to the value - for simple machine integers the value is immediate, for others is a bit trickier. The Murmur3-32 implementing function contains in fact an additional parameter (defaulted with 4, special case making behaving as in Wikipedia) which selects how many bits to choose from the expression struct in input. Since a normal expression is internally represented as an array of pointers, one can take the first, the second etc.. by repeatedly adding 4 (bytes = 32 bit) to the base pointer of the expression. So, passing 8 to the function will give the second pointer, 12 the third and so on. Since internal structs (big integers, machine integers, machine reals, big reals and so on) have different member variables (e.g. a machine integer has only a pointer to int, a complex 2 pointers to numbers etc..), for each expression struct there is a "wrapper" that combine its internal members in one single 32-bit hash (basically with FNV-1 rounds). The simplest expression to hash is an integer.

The `murmur3_32()` function has 1131470165 as seed, n=0 and other params as in Wikipedia.

So we have:

```
  hash_of_number = 16777619 * (84696351‬ ^ murmur3_32( &number ))
```

with " ^ " meaning XOR.
I really didn't try it - pointers are encoded using `WINAPI EncodePointer()`, so they can't be exploited at runtime. (May be worth running in Linux under Wine with a modified version of `EncodePonter`?)

---

### **64 BIT**

It uses a FNV-1 64 bit hash function with 0xAF63BD4C8601B7DF as offset basis and 0x100000001B3 as FNV prime, along with a [SIP64-24](https://github.com/veorq/SipHash/blob/master/siphash24.c) hash ([here](https://github.com/veorq/SipHash/blob/master/siphash24.c)'s the reference code) with the first 64 bit of 0x0AE3F68FE7126BBF76F98EF7F39DE1521 as k0 and the last 64 bit as k1. The function is applied to the base pointer of the expression and resolved internally. As in 32-bit's murmur3, there is an additional parameter (defaulted to 8) to select how many pointers to choose from the input expression struct. For each expression type there is a wrapper to condensate struct members into a single hash  by means of FNV-1 64 bit rounds.

For a machine integer, we have:

```
    hash_number_64bit = 0x100000001B3 * (0xAF63BD4C8601B7DF ^ SIP64_24( &number ))
```

Again, I didn't really try it. Could anyone try?

---

### **Not for the faint-hearted**

If you take a look at their [notes on internal implementation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html), they say that "Each expression contains a special form of hash code that is used both in pattern matching and evaluation."

The hash code they're referring to is the one generated by these functions - at some point in the normal expression wrapper function there's an assignment that puts the computed hash inside the expression struct itself.

It would certainly be cool to understand HOW they can make use of these hashes for pattern matching purpose. So I had a try running through the bigInteger wrapper to see what happens - that's the simplest compound expression.
It begins checking something that returns 1 - dunno what.
So it executes

```
    var1 = 16777619 * (67918732 ^ hashMachineInteger(1));
```

with hashMachineInteger() is what we said before - including values.

Then it reads the length in bytes of the bigInt from the struct (`bignum_length`) and runs

```
    result = 16777619 * (v10 ^ murmur3_32(v6, 4 * v4));
```

Note that `murmur3_32()` is called if `4 * bignum_length` is greater than 8 (may be related to the max value of machine integers `$MaxMachineNumber` `2^32^32` and by converse to what a bigInt is supposed to be).

So, the final code is

```
    if (bignum_length > 8){

    result = 16777619 * (16777619 * (67918732 ^ ( 16777619 * (84696351‬ ^ murmur3_32( 1, 4 )))) ^ murmur3_32( &bignum, 4 * bignum_length ));
    }
```

I've made some hypoteses on the properties of this construction. The presence of many XORs and the fact that `16777619 + 67918732 = 84696351‬` may make one think that some sort of cyclic structure is exploited to check patterns - i.e. subtracting the offset and dividing by the prime, or something like that. The software Cassandra uses the Murmur hash algorithm for token generation - see [these images](https://www.google.it/search?q=cassandra%20token%20generator&client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1366&bih=606&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWyqL1g87OAhUCtBQKHV2eDsg4ChD8BQgHKAI#imgrc=_) for what I mean with "cyclic structure". Maybe various primes are used for each expression - must still check.

---

*Hope it helps*

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Hash calls the internal Data`HashCode function, then divides it by 2, takes the first 20 digits of N[..] and then the IntegerPart, plus one, that is:

```
    IntegerPart[N[Data`HashCode[expr]/2, 20]] + 1
```

Comment: interesting observation, but I think not quite right: ``Tally[(IntegerPart[N[Data`HashCode[#]/2, 20]] + 1) - Hash[#] & /@ 
  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 1000]]`` gives `{{0, 256}, {2, 273}, {1, 471}}`

Comment: this seems to work: ``myhash[exp_] := ( (# + Mod[#, 2] - 4 Floor[(Mod[#, 4] + 1)/4]) &@ 
    Data`HashCode[exp])/2``